# Deleting a conversation and sending a message to same conversation

Tags: database-design

I'm creating a messaging app that has conversations and messages. Each conversation has a sequence of messages.

If User 1 deletes a conversation with User 2, I have a field in my Conversation table called deleted_users which contains an array of users which have deleted the conversation. Thus User 2 will still see the conversation but User 1 will not.

The problem: what if User 2 decides to send a message to User 1 with this same conversation (that User 1 deleted but User 2 still has). It seems to me that this message should create a whole new conversation for User 1, but still belong to the original conversation for User 2. What's the best way to handle this?

I'm using Parse.com for saving the data. They use Mongo I think...

Comment: Please, *please* do not put an array of objects into a single table field. This is hell to work with using SQL (and violates 1st normal form). Use a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).

Comment: @sleske I'm using Parse.com, so they take care of this functionality for me. They use Mongo I think...

Comment: @A user: Thanks, that's important information. I edited it into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit of the KISS principle, why not just "resurrect" the conversation?

Chances are the user deleted the conversation because they believed it was over. Now that there is a reply, they might want to see the conversation again.
To avoid confusion, you might want to show some marker/notification ("Deleted conversation, undeleted because of reply.").

Then you can try to get user feedback. Based on that, refine further (e.g. have a button to decline further messages).

Most messaging applications I know work like that. If they have the concept of "conversation" (not all do), usually a conversation is just a new window. You can close the window, but it will re-open if a new message comes in, with all the old messages present.

---

You might also want to think about what it means to "delete" a conversation. Why would a user want that? What is the difference to just "closing" or "hiding" a conversation? That should help you figure out what the right behaviour is when a message comes in for a "deleted" conversation.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that's very helpful. However, in the scenario where one user "Deletes Permanently" the conversation (Facebook does this) then how would I create an efficient method to only download messages from a certain point? Would I create another field in my conversation table that has a date associated with a user's deletion?

Comment: did you see the above comment?

Comment: @Auser: Yes, what you propose should work. To really answer we'd need more details about the table design you have in mind. Edit your answer and indicate where exactly you are unsure.